# 'mat-table' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use mat-table in my project. I have imported angular material component in seperate module and that module i have imported in component parent module. but still getting the error

> 'mat-table' is not a known element

this is my material module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//Angular Material Components
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatPaginatorModule
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatPaginatorModule
    ]
})
export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

this is my component parent module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './../angular-material/angular-material.module';

import { InventoryUploadComponent } from './inventory-upload/inventory-upload.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        InventoryUploadComponent
    ],
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      AngularMaterialModule
  ]
})
export class MasterModule { }
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: You try to use in InventoryUploadComponent ?

Comment: I tried that also.

Comment: Tried what? Can you please post component and html?

Comment: I mean I tried to import material component in my Component as well...

Comment: please add your template and component. Importin component wont help